# lang attribute Vs meta tags charset attribute

Tags: html, character-encoding, web

The w3c points out the use of `lang` attribute as

> Assisting search engines
>
> Assisting speech synthesizers
>
> Helping a user agent select glyph variants for high quality typography
>
> Helping a user agent choose a set of quotation marks
>
> Helping a user agent make decisions about hyphenation, ligatures, and
>   spacing
>
> Assisting spell checkers and grammar checkers

But I found nothing useful for `charset` attribute of `meta` tag except for encoding the document

Do `charset` provide the same functionality as the `lang` attribute such as ***assisting speech synthesizers,search engines***.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meta-tag defines your used charset/encoding like UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or something like that.
While the html lang tag defines the used language like en-EN, de-DE and so on.

Comment: As I pointed out in the NOTE,the lang attribute assists search engines,speech synthesizers.. But does charset does the same

Comment: no the charset defines the used encoding, which is neccessary to view your page right. so you can use a german lang-tag while you're using a chinese encoding

Comment: so basically both assist in using multiple languages in the page!

Comment: roughly spoken, yes. one tells the searchengine/browser which language is "spoken" and the other one tells how to show the used characters, or rather with charset/encoding is needed to show it right.

Comment: There is no evidence of any search engine actually making any use of `lang` attributes. A few speech synthesizers utilize them to some extent. Most texts about `lang` attributes are just descriptions of what could or should happen. Character encoding indications, on the other hand, are crucial, for no character data makes any sense without applying some character encoding, but relative to a process where e.g. `meta` tags get trumped by HTTP headers.

Answer (score 5):

It’s easier to say what they have in common: nothing. Well, except for being metadata of some kind and for being relevant in internationalization.

And the correct form is `<meta charset="encoding name">`, such as `<meta charset=utf-8>`. It’s not about languages but about the interpretation of bytes in the document as characters. Some encodings have been developed for specific languages, but encoding and language are still quite distinct concepts.

`<meta charset="...">` is HTML5 shorthand for

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=...">`, which is described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html)